# Transpile Model View Controller in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs, rollupjs

I want to use Gulp, Rollup and Babel to transpile ES6 app to ES5 (that use the module reveal pattern with IIFE).

The gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rollup = require('gulp-better-rollup');
var babel = require('rollup-plugin-babel');

gulp.task('roll', function () {
    return gulp.src('_01_src/js/form/*.js')
        .pipe(rollup(
            {plugins: [babel({presets: ['es2015-rollup']})]},
            {format: 'iife',}
            )
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_02_build/js/form/'));
});
```

The controller import model and view and is transpiled ok:

```
var controller = (function (model) {
'use strict';

model = 'default' in model ? model['default'] : model;

var classCallCheck = function (instance, Constructor) {
  if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
    throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
  }
};

var Cat = function Cat(name) {
    classCallCheck(this, Cat);

    this.name = name;
};

return Cat;

}(model));
```

The problem that I have is when I want to group together (to avoid collision) like this is not working:

```
( function() { var model = function () { ... }()
var view = function () { ... }()
var controller = function (model, view) {   
    ......
}(model, view) )}()
```

I have multiple app that contains MVC and I want first to group and app together than group all app;

So I start:

```
js
app1
 - model.js
 - view.js
 - controller.js
app2
 - model.js
 - view.js
 - controller.js
app3
 - model.js
 - view.js
 - controller.js
```

After task run I want to have, which don't collide:

```
  js
   app1.js
   app2.js
   app3.js
```

Comment: Is webpack an option?

Comment: I don't want to use webpack because I want to use IIFE and avoid webpack module bloat.  https://nolanlawson.com/2016/08/15/the-cost-of-small-modules/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have partial working example from the [rollup-stream in github](https://github.com/Permutatrix/rollup-stream/issues/14#issuecomment-311566301) team/users, but only works for an app(and not exactly transpiled as MVC), not with multiple apps.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const scss = require('gulp-sass');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const watch = require('gulp-watch');
const autopre = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const rollup = require('rollup-stream');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

gulp.task('rollup', function () {
    return rollup({
        entry: '_01_src/js/form/app.js',
        format: 'iife',
    })
    // turn the raw text stream into a stream containing one streaming Vinyl file.
    .pipe(source('form.js'))
    // buffer that file's contents. most gulp plugins don't support streaming files.
    .pipe(buffer())
    // transform the files.
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    // and output to _02_build/js/form.js as normal.
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_02_build/js'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

would this help? I think create tasks for each app, you mentioned before group together it transpile OK

```js
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const gulp = require('gulp')
const rollup = require('gulp-better-rollup')
const babel = require('rollup-plugin-babel');

// suppose your project looks like
// --project
// | +-gulpfile.js
// | +-src
// | |  +-app1
// | |  |  +-controller.js
// | |  |  +-model.js
// | |  |  +-view.js
// | |  +-app2

// the target path where your apps locates, 
var targetPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src')

// files will build into
var destTargetPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dest')

// find app1,app2.... and exclude node_modules
var dirs = fs.readdirSync(targetPath).filter((filename) => {
  if (filename === 'node_modules') return false
  var stat = fs.statSync(path.join(targetPath, filename))
  return stat.isDirectory()
})

// I want a task name for each app
var dir2task = dir => 'x_' + dir

// add tasks for each app
dirs.forEach((dir) => {
  // as it worked for single app
  gulp.task(dir2task(dir), () => {
    //this return means tells gulp when job is done
    return gulp.src(path.join(targetPath, dir) + '/**/*.js')
      .pipe(rollup({
        plugins: [babel({
          presets: ['es2015-rollup']
        })]
      }, {
        format: 'iife',
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(destTargetPath, dir)))
  })
})

// run them all and after all apps built,and copy or rename your built controller to appx.js, there's no need for return, my mistake
gulp.task('default', dirs.map(dir2task), () => {
  dirs.forEach((dir) => {
    fs.copySync(path.join(destTargetPath, dir, 'controller.js'), path.join(destTargetPath, dir + '.js'))
  })
})

// result will be
// --project
// | +-gulpfile.js
// | +-src
// | |  +-app1
// | |  +-....
// | +-dist
// | |  +-app1.js
// | |  +-app2.js
```

Comment: I doesn't return/create a folder or transpiled file. Maybe you can give me more details, comments inside the code. Maybe because you don't return anything ing gulp task, in code you have: " return
  })"

Answer (score -1):

You can use static variable.
Here's how to make model, view, and controller as static variable.

```
function a_project () {
 }
a_project.model = function(){};
a_project.view = function(){};
a_project.controller = function(){};

var myInstance = new MyClass();
```

This will help you to call model, view and controller variable.

Comment: ok, but that was an example of what I want to look after transpiling from ES6 to ES5, my issue is with the transpiled part and task runner

Comment: If you define static variable you can call it like before and there will be no problem.

Comment: Static is not an option if you do not have control over the page. The point of using modules is to hide this stuff from the page and other code that doesn't need it.